# VisualStudio creates conflict when checking in model.bim files

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ssas-tabular

I have a weird problem working in VisualStudio 2019, with cube .bim files.

I usually work on a model.bim, make some changes and then I check in the file... If someone else makes changes in model.bim I will always get this conflict:
[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I don't know if I remember correctly but back in the days I remember seeing some option to check out w/ a lock on a file. With that option other users can't check in their changes while they don't own a lock.